# aws - How many users can a small ec2 serve

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

If you take an average dynamic web site, what would be peak number of users that one small ec2 instance could serve concurrently. Please don't send "it depends..." answers, I need some crudest estimation. Thanks.

Comment: What web server software will you be using? NGINX / APACHE / IIS? Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: The average of every web tech used and variable included in the process of serving web users (I know it's too vague)

Answer (score 3):

Well... it depends! :) I am sure you are able to serve really a lot of static images with a high performance webserver like nginx. But you will only be able to serve a small number of users if you have a complete Java enterprise stack.

There are so many factors in this that you can not give at least the crudest estimation. Some points to consider is your app, the processing it does, how many resources it needs, your server infrastructure... too many variables to give a correct answer.

Therefore I suggest the following: develop a comparable set of test tools. Try to mimic the load pattern of your users as close as possible (it would for example be possible to replay an Apache access log). Measure how many requests you will be able to serve. Tune your config, measure again. Change servers, measure again. This is the only way to get any results.

Tools include [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/), [multi-mechanize](http://code.google.com/p/multi-mechanize/), [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) and probably a lot more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and suggested tools:) I concluded the same process is the most logical, but it never hurts to ask. It would be nice if there was some resource to find out this questions in advance :)